# How can I auto-fill Edit fields by using different options of a drop-down list?

Tags: delphi, drop-down-menu, edit, autofill

am using a VCL form in Delphi, where I have put about 10 edit boxes.
These Edit boxes contain values that are related to specific models of solar panels.
These values are needed in order to calculate the output power of a solar panel.
So far, I am able to type these values in every run with the command:

```
c0:= StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
```

for c0 to c10. But, instead of asking the user to manually type these 10 values in each run, is there any way to let the user select one option (i.e. a model of a solar panel) of a drop down list and these values being filled automatically for them?

Does the combobox do such a thing and if yes, how exactly? I am sorry, I am a very new Delphi user. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the TComboBox.OnSelect event to change the 10 edit.Text properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the combo box `Style` to `csDropDownList`.
2. Populate the combo box `Items` with appropriate values for the user to select.
3. Add an `OnSelect` event handler. This will fire whenever the user selects a new item in the combo box.
4. Implement the `OnSelect` event handler by populating the edit controls with appropriate values, based on the value of `ItemIndex`.

You will need to think a little about the UI. If the user changes the combo box selection, then the edit control values change. But can the user then modify the edit controls? Now the values in the edit controls no longer match the combo box. Is that what you want? I guess that the UI needs a little more polish.

Comment: @ David: I created the box and its options under the TForm2.FormCreate option. I added the values of the edits using "if" statements as: if ComboBox1.ItemIndex=0 then Edit1.Text:=FloatToStr(some double). It worked but everytime I choose an option from combobox it recreates the same options and combobox grows bigger...The OnSelect is on FormCreate.What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: You need to populate the combo box and set its properties once when the form loads. `FormCreate` is fine for that. Don't add more items in the `OnSelect` handler because that fires repeatedly. That handler fires whenever the user selected a new item. You want to respond to the user selection in the `OnSelect` handler.

Comment: Thank you, I had to create a Combobox1Select event and put my if statements in there. Also, for the UI I do not want the user to interfere with the values so I made the edit boxes as read-only.